# Why does my Linux prompt show only ">" sign?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I m learning very basic Linux command where i was typing very basic command ,and i don't know exactly what i typed or happened i got only  ">" in my terminal.

Don't know what i should type?

Thanks

Comment: http://linuxcommand.org/learning_the_shell.php

Answer (score 4):

This is shown when the terminal is expecting you to finish typing in your command. For example:

`git commit -m 'asdasdasdasd <enter>`
will lead to a `>` shown in the next line, because the terminal is waiting for you to finish the input (because you haven't typed in the closing `'` sign).

Answer (score 2):

What command have you typed? Try Ctrl+C .

Comment: Hey!!! thanks now it's working again as same , thanks.